# Dynamically change ProxyCreationEnabled

Tags: entity-framework

Is it Ok? if i will dynamically change value of ProxyCreationEnabled configuration in EF 4.3?

```
    somecontext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
    somecontext.Set().Get(id);
    somecontext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = true;
    ...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. It is actually sometimes very useful to change the proxy creation or lazy loading configuration at runtime.